# how to used python code to search for the number of xlsm file in a folder?

Tags: python, django

In a folder I have unknown xlsm file, how I used python code to do some searching and print out the number of the xlsm file.

Anyone can share idea with me?

Comment: I would start by writing some code.

Comment: You can use listdir + fnmatch.
Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch

Comment: `the number of the xlsm file` Means what? Its contents? Name? Some metadata?

Comment: mean in a folder contain x number of excel file

Comment: any suggestion ? because still no idea on it

Answer (score 1):

```
fileCounter=0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myPath):
    for file in files:    
        if file.endswith('.xlsm'):
            fileCounter+= 1

print("The number of .xlsm files in your directory is: ",fileCounter)
```